# How to check if a variable is binary in Python

Tags: python

In order to check if a given `list` is constituted only by `0` and `1` values, I tried to set up a function returning `True` when the `list` is binary, while it returns `False` when not:

**My code**

```
def is_binary(y):
    for x in y:
        if x in [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]:
            return False
            break
        else:
            return True
```

Itried it on the following list:

```
our_list=[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]
is_binary(our_list)
```

Output:

```
True
```

But it doesn't work when the variable is not binary.
Any help from your side will be appreciated.

Comment: You return on the first number regardless of what this number is. You'll never check anything past the first number. Move `return True` outside the for loop. Also, wouldn't checking if `x not in [0, 1]` be much more intuitive and clear?

Comment: You could use all: `all(x in {0,1} for x in our_list)`

Comment: It might be nicer to do something like `not in [0, 1]` for the edge case where you have a `list` with something other than `int`s.

Comment: You can simply `return all(x in [0,1] for x in y)`.

Comment: `set(our_list) <= {0, 1}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use a list comprehension with the result of checking if each element is binary, and use `all` to check that all elements are True.

Edit: as @Jonh Coleman suggested, instead of creating a list first and then applying `all`, we can take advantage of generators, which will only generate values as requested.

We then only need to generate elements until one of them evaluates False. `all` will take care of that by shortcircuiting and not continuing to request elements to the generator once one of them evaluates False. That will be both more memory and time efficient.

```
our_list=[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,2,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]

all(i in [0,1] for i in our_list)

False
```

Comment: Numpy is completely pointless there, as built-in `all` does exactly the same job.

Comment: Ah, I didn't know python had a builtin all, I always used the numpy one, thanks

Comment: Creating a list in memory just to run `all` on it is inefficient. `all(i in [0,1] for i in our_list)` is enough. For cases in which `our_list` is large but not boolean, the generator approach could short-circuit early whereas the list-based approach will process the whole list.

Answer (score 1):

I would turn around your logic.

```
def is_binary(y):
    for x in y:
        if x not in [0,1]:
             return False
    return True
```

The root of the problem is that you are returning the result at the first iteration round, because the return statement stops the execution of the function. This also makes your break statement redundant. See https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-return-statement/ for more info.

There are two use cases where your original solution works as expected and that is when the list length is one or the error is in the first item of the list `y` AND the "wrong" value is in the list `[0,1, ...9]` e.g. `y=[0]` or `y=[1]` or `y=[1,0]` returns `True` and `y=[3]` will return `False`. However, your solution fails, if `y=['three']` or `y=[13]` or `y=[0, 0, 3]` because it returns `True`, though it should be `False`.

Comment: The `break` command is not the root cause. The root cause is the `if-else` statement.

Comment: Yes, this was actually a mistake in my answer formatting. I wanted to point out that the root of the problem is the return statement that ends the execution @GodWin. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 1):

```py
def is_binary(arr):
    for num in arr:
        if num not in [0, 1]:
            return False
    return True
    
our_list=[1,0,0,0,1,1,0,0,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,1,1]
print(is_binary(our_list))
```

I found several mistakes in your code.

Firstly, your code stops when the `return` statement is executed. So your loop will only be executed once and return the result of the first element in the list.

Secondly, there are two binary numbers, and countless numbers that aren't binary. You're just checking if the numbers are in range(2, 10). When the number is not in that range, take 11 as example, since it is not in range(2, 10), it won't execute the `return False` statement.

Therefore, rather to check if the number is in countless un-binary numbers, check if the number is not binary.

Comment: Thank you @Yeyang, your answer works but I want a short solution